# (Done) Re-Open Coworker stole code entirely and claims he wrote it all

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I took a stab at an edit for [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120614/coworker-stole-code-entirely-and-claims-he-wrote-it-all).

The original question was a bit of a rant and asked quite a few questions. I chopped it down to what I believe is the actual question and tried to simplify it.

I would like to propose with my edit, we re-open the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the edit was good, so I went and casted the 5th vote to reopen it.